# XML Schema validation(XSD)

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb2

I just want to know how the XSD validation happening behind the scene.
If i define the XSD as follows

```
<xs:simpleType name="MaxText">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="10000000000000"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

To do the actual validation of string length, does java need to load the whole string value of XML to memory? If that is the case, there is a potential issue of throwing the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".

Appreciate any comments.

Regards,
Mayuran

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on the implementation of the XML parser and schema validator, but I think it very likely that most implementations will require each text node (or attribute value) to fit within the limits of a Java (etc) string.

I think we're going to see an increasing incidence of problems in the next few years as we hit the 2^31 limit on sizes of strings, arrays, etc. It's going to be very tough to redesign programming languages like Java to get over this, since the use of (int) data type for addressing into such structures is so universal.